# Robolectric tests are supported for JetPack Compose now – but not working

Tags: android, android-testing, robolectric, android-jetpack-compose

Robolectric tests are supposedly supported now by Jetpack Compose, since [beta09](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-ui#1.0.0-beta09). But I attempted to implement a very simple test (the [test for the feature in AOSP](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/changes/30/1699930/12/compose/ui/ui-test-junit4/src/test/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/test/junit4/RobolectricComposeTest.kt), see `runClickScenario()`) but it does not work for me. Error I get is:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class androidx.test.espresso.base.ThreadPoolExecutorExtractor$2 cannot access a member of class androidx.loader.content.ModernAsyncTask with modifiers "public static final"
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class androidx.test.espresso.base.ThreadPoolExecutorExtractor$2 cannot access a member of class androidx.loader.content.ModernAsyncTask with modifiers "public static final"
    at androidx.test.espresso.Espresso.onIdle(Espresso.java:15)
    at androidx.test.espresso.Espresso.onIdle(Espresso.java:1)
    at androidx.compose.ui.test.junit4.android.EspressoLink_androidKt.runEspressoOnIdle(EspressoLink.android.kt:91)
    at androidx.compose.ui.test.junit4.RobolectricIdlingStrategy$runUntilIdle$1.invoke(RobolectricIdlingStrategy.android.kt:69)
    at androidx.compose.ui.test.junit4.RobolectricIdlingStrategy$runUntilIdle$1.invoke(RobolectricIdlingStrategy.android.kt:51)
    at androidx.compose.ui.test.junit4.AndroidSynchronization_androidKt.runOnUiThread(AndroidSynchronization.android.kt:33)
    at androidx.compose.ui.test.junit4.RobolectricIdlingStrategy.runUntilIdle(RobolectricIdlingStrategy.android.kt:51)
    at androidx.compose.ui.test.junit4.AndroidComposeTestRule.waitForIdle(AndroidComposeTestRule.android.kt:293)
    at androidx.compose.ui.test.junit4.AndroidComposeTestRule.waitForIdle(AndroidComposeTestRule.android.kt:286)
    at androidx.compose.ui.test.junit4.AndroidComposeTestRule.setContent(AndroidComposeTestRule.android.kt:281)
```

(next line in stack trace is my test code.)

I am using:

- compose 1.0.0
- kotlin 1.5.10
- espresso 3.4.0
- robolectric 4.6.1

It did not matter whether I ran the test in AS or on command line.

Answer (score 12):

I didn't find this when searching before, but the problem is with Robolectric. Fortunately, there's a workaround.

See [issue, comments with workaround](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/6593#issuecomment-876844270) for reference.